# Dynamic SQL w/ Loop Over All Columns in a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I recently was pulled off of an ASP.net conversion project at my new job to help with a rather slow, mundane, but desperate task another department is handling.  Basically, they are using a simple SQL script on every column of every table in every database (it's horrible) to generate a count of all of the distinct records on each table for each column.  My SQL experience is limited and my dynamic SQL experience is zero, more or less, but since I have not been given permissions yet to even access this particular database I went to work attempting to formulate a more automated query to perform this task, testing on a database I do have access to.

In short, I ran into some issues and I was hoping someone might be able to help me fill in the blanks.  It'll save this department more than a month of speculated time if something more automated can be utilized.

These are the two scripts I was given and told to run on each column.  The first one was for any non-bit/boolean column and also for non-datetime columns.  The second was to be used for any datetime column.

```
select columnName, count(*) qty
from tableName
group by columnName
order by qty desc

select year(a.columnName), count(*) qty
from tableName a
group by year(a.columnName)
order by qty desc
```

Doing this thousands of times doesn't seem like a lot of fun to me, so here is more or less some pseudo-code that I came up with that I think could solve the issue, I will point out which areas I am fuzzy on.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(2500)

set @sql = 'the first part(s) of statement'
```

[pseudo-pseudo] Get "List" of All Column Names in Table (I do not believe there is a Collection datatype in SQL code, but you get the idea)

[pseudo-pseudo] Loop Through "List" of Column Names

(I know this dot notation wouldn't work, but I would like to perform something similar to this)

```
IF ColumnName.DataType LIKE 'date%'
set @sql = @sql + ' something'

IF ColumnName.DataType = bit
set @sql = @sql + ' something else' --actually it'd be preferable to skip bit/boolean datatypes      if possible as these aren't necessary for the reports being created by these queries

ELSE
set @sql = @sql + ' something other than something else'

set @sql = @sql + ' ending part of statement'

EXEC(@sql)
```

So to summarize, for simplicity's sake I'd like to let the user plug the table's name into a variable at the start of the query:

```
declare @tableName nvarchar(50)
set @tableName = 'TABLENAME' --Enter Query's Table Name Here
```

Based on this, the code will loop through every column of that table, checking for datatype.  If the datatype is a datetime (or other date like datatype), the "year" code would be added to the dynamic SQL.  If it is anything else (except bit/boolean), then it will add the default logic to the dynamic SQL code.

Again, for simplicity's sake (even if it is bad practice) I figure the end result will be a dynamic SQL statement with multiple selects, one for each column in the table.  Then the user would simply copy the output to excel (which they are doing right now anyway).  I know this isn't the perfect solution so I am open to suggestions, but since time is of the essence and my experience with dynamic SQL is close to null, I thought a somewhat quick and dirty approach would be tolerable in this case.

I do apologize for my very haphazard preparation with this question but I do hope someone out there might be able to steer me in the right direction.

Thanks so much for your time, I certainly appreciate it.

Comment: `select o.name, c.name from sysobjects o inner join syscolumns c on o.id = c.id where o.name = 'tableName'`  Take a look at those results

Comment: Very nice indeed, though I am curious if there is any simple way to loop through these so that they might be individually added to the dynamic SQL so it can all be performed in a single statement?

Comment: Just wondering why this is being done. Introducing surrogoate ids?

Comment: The end result is that I need a report of every column on every table showing how many times a record is used in that column.  The output would, for example, the columns in the output would be the Column Name and the Quantity.  Each record would look like: RECORD1, 19483.  RECORD2, 18495.  RECORD3, 14594.  Etc.

Comment: @Varwulf, sure there is a way.  Declare a cursor for that query.  Build up your sql based on the type indicated in syscolumns.  I'd do it as an answer, but cannot currently.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example working through all the suggestions in the comments.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
declare stat_cursor cursor local fast_forward for
select
    case when x.name not in ('date', 'datetime2', 'smalldatetime', 'datetime') then

N'select
    ' + quotename(s.name, '''') + ' as schema_name,
    ' + quotename(t.name, '''') + ' as table_name,
    ' + quotename(c.name) + ' as column_name,
    count(*) qty
from
    ' + quotename(s.name) + '.' + quotename(t.name) + '
group by 
    ' + quotename(c.name) + '
order by 
    qty desc;'

    else

N'select
    ' + quotename(s.name, '''') + ' as schema_name,
    ' + quotename(t.name, '''') + ' as table_name,
    year(' + quotename(c.name) + ') as column_name,
    count(*) qty
from
    ' + quotename(s.name) + '.' + quotename(t.name) + '
group by 
    year(' + quotename(c.name) + ')
order by 
    qty desc;'

    end

from
    sys.schemas s
        inner join
    sys.tables t
        on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
        inner join
    sys.columns c
        on c.object_id = t.object_id
        inner join
    sys.types x
        on c.system_type_id = x.user_type_id
where
    x.name not in (
        'geometry',
        'geography',
        'hierarchyid',
        'xml',
        'timestamp',
        'bit',
        'image',
        'text',
        'ntext'
    );

open stat_cursor;

fetch next from stat_cursor into @sql;

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    exec sp_executesql @sql;
    fetch next from stat_cursor into @sql;
end;

close stat_cursor;
deallocate stat_cursor;
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/35170/2) (note this only shows the first iteration through the cursor. Not sure if this is a limitation of SQLFiddle or a bug).

I'd probably stash the results into a separate database if I was doing this. Also, I'd probably put the SQL building bits into user defined functions for maintainability (the slow bit will be running the queries, no point optimizing generating them).

Comment: Excellent implementation.

Comment: This was pretty slick actually, I tried to grasp and understand it (was a bit of a lost cause, cursors are entirely new to me).  And it ran beautifully for a bit.  Unfortunately, since we have virtual machines where I work and we are not allocated a lot of resources, I actually ran out of memory while executing the query, I presume, from all of the output/results displaying on Management Studio.  I was wondering if there might be a way to completely skip the displaying of the results and quickly write them to Excel instead?  Preferably, with the Sheet names being named after the column name?

Comment: Create a table in a different database with `schema_name`, `table_name`, `column_value, count_of_values` and rewrite the dynamic sql to insert the results there instead of selecting them. Or just use the same database an exclude the table from the cursor query.

Comment: I may or may not be able to obtain write permissions to the database since it is from another department.  In fact, I attempted to reconfigure ‘Ad Hoc Distributed Queries’, 1; to attempt an OPENROWSET to excel and I don't have permissions to make that change either.  It seems I am kind of stuck.

Comment: @Varwulf You'll probably have more luck writing it in Excel using VBA if you want the results in Excel. I'd ask for a separate database if they're scared of you having write access on this one. Then use db.schema.table to insert across.