# SQL Server: quick and dirty data validation query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Getting frequent updates on a database that is going through major changes. Need a quick way to check for abnormalities in the data. Over 1,000 tables; about 200 
actually being used.

Would like to have a list of the tables with the most records at the top. Found and modified this code that seems to work:

```
select 
    object_name(object_id) AS TableName, 
    sum(rows) AS TableRowCount
from 
    sys.partitions
where 
    index_id in (0, 1)
group by 
    object_id
order by 
    TableRowCount desc
```

However, it would be useful to also have an indication if columns are populated properly. Would be great to have percentages of valid rows as well as percentages of NULLs, blanks and zeros.

Stumbled across this snippet:

```
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    dbo.ExecuteScalarToInt('SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.00/count(*), 0) Percentage FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)) Percentage
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

However, this throws an error:

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.ExecuteScalarToInt", or the name is ambiguous.

Hmmm.  I deleted the `dbo.ExecuteScalarToInt` part:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    ('SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.00/count(*), 0) Percentage FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)) AS Percentage 
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
ORDER BY 
    TABLE_NAME ASC, COLUMN_NAME ASC
```

This works, but for the percentage column, a SQL query shows up. Tried the resulting SQL query--it works.

Tried substituting "exec", "sp_executesql", and "exec sp_executesql".
Got errors.

Here is what I'm imagining what the output should look similar to:

```
TableName      TableRows       ColumnName     PctPopulatedRows        PctNULLs         PctBlanks        PctZeros
LineItems      4,649,764       InventryNum        100.0%                0.0%              0.0%            0.0%
LineItems      4,649,764       Description         99.9%                0.0%              0.1%            0.0%
LineItems      4,649,764       Price               99.7%                0.0%              0.1%            0.2%
.
.
.
Invoices         385,532       InvoiceNum         100.0%                0.0%              0.0%            0.0%  
Invoices         385,532       DateTime            99.6%                0.2%              0.1%            0.1% 
Invoices         385,532       TotalAmt            99.8%                0.0%              0.2%            0.0% 
.
.
.
Customers         64,906       CustomerNum        100.0%                0.0%              0.0%            0.0% 
Customers         64,906       CustStreet          99.8%                0.0%              0.2%            0.0% 
Customers         64,906       CustZip             99.7%                0.1%              0.2%            0.0%
```

Tired of banging my head against this.  Can anyone straighten me out to get closer to a solution?

Many thanks for taking a look.

Comment: `ExecuteScalarToInt` is a custom scalar user defined function. Wherever you lifted that from might have the definition for it. You'd need to create it in the same database. If a NULL or blank is legitimately an invalid piece of data then you should have constraints stopping that. Of course in the real world that can be difficult.

Comment: What you required can be done but not in one single query but utilize dynamic sql + temp table. Looks like it will be a complex query (the dynamic part)

Comment: You basically need to use a cursor to populate some dynamic SQL... like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559088/dynamic-sql-w-loop-over-all-columns-in-a-table